# Compute date difference in days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I've got a dataframe that looks like this

```
    date        id
0   2019-01-15  c-15-Jan-2019-0
1   2019-01-26  c-26-Jan-2019-1
2   2019-02-02  c-02-Feb-2019-2
3   2019-02-15  c-15-Feb-2019-3
4   2019-02-23  c-23-Feb-2019-4
```

and I'd like to create a new column called 'days_since' that shows the number of days that have gone by since the last record. For instance, the new column would be

```
    date        id              days_since
0   2019-01-15  c-15-Jan-2019-0 NaN
1   2019-01-26  c-26-Jan-2019-1 11
2   2019-02-02  c-02-Feb-2019-2 5
3   2019-02-15  c-15-Feb-2019-3 13
4   2019-02-23  c-23-Feb-2019-4 7
```

I tried to use

`df_c['days_since'] = df_c.groupby('id')['date'].diff().apply(lambda x: x.days)`

but that just returned a column full of null values. The date column is full of datetime objects. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `'id'` doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's a unique column in the dataframe

Comment: Aren't there 7 days between 2019-01-26 and 2019-02-02?

Comment: `df_c.groupby('id')` is a total red herring, you shouldn't do it, it will mess you up; in fact we don't even need to see `id` column. All you want to do is compute `.diff()` on `df['date']` column, that simple. PS assuming that is that `df['date']` column is sorted in increasing order?

Comment: Other minor issue: your example shows the result is apparently a column of int but with a NaN, which is impossible. Either you get floats, or can't have NaN. Which do you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you make it too complicated, given the `date` column contains datetime data, you can use:

```
>>> df['date'].diff()
0       NaT
1   11 days
2    7 days
3   13 days
4    8 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

or if you want the number of days:

```
>>> df['date'].diff().dt.days
0     NaN
1    11.0
2     7.0
3    13.0
4     8.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

So you can assign the number of days with:

```
df['days_since'] = df['date'].diff().dt.days
```

This gives us:

```
>>> df
        date  days_since
0 2019-01-15         NaN
1 2019-01-26        11.0
2 2019-02-02         7.0
3 2019-02-15        13.0
4 2019-02-23         8.0
```

Comment: ...and finally convert to int with `.astype(int)`; but that won't allow NaN values